# Rails use attributes as string in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the gem Alchemist to make unit conversions.
Given this working in my model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    def converted
        quantity = 1
        quantity.kg.to.g
    end
end
```

How do I make kg and g dynamic? Like:

```
quantity.unit_purchase.to.unit_inventory
```

`unit_purchase` and `unit_inventory` are attributes (strings) of the class, corresponding to values such as kg, g and so on.

So perhaps something like:

```
x = self.unit_purchase
y = self.unit_inventory
quantity.x.to.y
```

But I'm having hard time to find the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this the hard way:

```
unit_purchase = :kg
unit_inventory = :g
quantity.send(unit_purchase).to.send(unit_inventory)
```

That depends on knowing with *absolute certainty* that the two arguments are valid and aren't something hostile supplied by the user.

A safer way is to define a more arbitrary conversion method like:

```
quantity.convert(from_unit: unit_purchase, to_unit: unit_inventory)
```

Where that can check the arguments accordingly and `raise` on unexpected values.

Comment: unit_purchase comes from database. It's an attribute on the current class. Why would I set it to kg? That makes it static. The second solution does not follow syntax required by the Gem

Comment: I updated the question with what I have been trying before posting the question.

Comment: The 2 arguments are always valid as the user just enters the item and each item has unit_purchase and unit_inventory set correctly by default.

Comment: @Catmal I'd be a lot more paranoid than that. Do `unit_purchase` or `unit_inventory` ever come anywhere near user input? Are you sure that will always be the case? Do you have an explicit whitelist somewhere to ensure that the units will never conflict with a "real" method name? You can bob for apples in a bucket of fishhooks if you want but why risk it when there are safer options?

Comment: By editing an item, user can modify them, but it's from a list of closed choices. For instance if the current is g it can only be changed to kg or dg etc.. but not km or l. And I doubt they will ever confict with a real method name.

Comment: @Catmal just because the U/I constrains these values does not mean you cannot make a request from outside the U/I via mechanisms like `curl`, `postman`, etc. The values should at a minimum be validated in the model before saving and certainly validated before transformation when using a `send` mechanism.

Comment: I'll explain better. Item has the attributes unit_purchase and unit_inventory. These are validated and whitelisted when an Item is added or updated. quantity above corresponds to(simplified) item.purchases.sum(:quantity). The method above sums total purchases and converts the result from unit_purchase to unit_inventory. When the method is called, there's no user input involved. The frontend only sends item.id with the request. The backend finds the item and replies with item.converted.